# Unable to set fdw_startup_cost for postgres_fdw server

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I would like to change the default value for the option fdw_startup_cost for an existing postgres_fdw server but am getting an error message stating that option `fdw_startup_cost` is not found, even though its an option according to the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/postgres-fdw.html).

I'm using version 12.8 of PostgreSQL and the code used to set up the server is as follows:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;

CREATE SERVER my_server_name
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
  OPTIONS (host 'myhost.whatever.com', dbname 'my_database_name', fetch_size '50000', use_remote_estimate 'true');
```

Command I'm using to change the settings is:

```
ALTER SERVER prd_rtl_fdw OPTIONS (SET fdw_startup_cost '1000000000000000');
```

The error message is:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
ALTER SERVER prd_rtl_fdw OPTIONS (SET fdw_startup_cost '1000000000000000')

ERROR: option "fdw_startup_cost" not found
1 statement failed.
```

If I create a new server I can use this option (and it is applied successfully):

```
CREATE SERVER my_new_server_name
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
  OPTIONS (host 'myhost.whatever.com', dbname 'my_database_name', 
  fetch_size '50000', use_remote_estimate 'true', fdw_startup_cost '1000000000000000');
```

but creating a new server is not really an option unfortunately for operational reasons.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your statement would be correct if the option were already set and you want to change the value.  But since the option is not set yet, you need to use

```
ALTER SERVER prd_rtl_fdw OPTIONS (ADD fdw_startup_cost '1000000000000000');
```